# Large memory size allocation to a buffer of type int

Tags: c++, types, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am doing a visual c++ appliction and trying to allocate size to a buffer(that buffer is further used to store the contents of a stream). 
There is no problem if the size declared to buffer is less then

```
const int size= 319000; //here there is no problem
```

but for accessing some data of my desire from stream i need to declare the buffer of size like this-

```
const int size=4348928;//this size cause the problem
char buffer[size+1];
HRESULT hr = pStream->Read(buffer, size, &cbRead );
```

Although the last two line of the code has no role to play with my problem it is just to give you idea that what exactly i am doing with this buffer's size.

But when i declare this size it does nothing (i mean my visual application  function  like this: if you click a file it generate a stream and i am storing that stream in a buffer- and if i declare the size of the order of 319000 the programs run fine and when increase the size to 4348928  it even don't work- and of course there is no error )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `buffer` is a local variable, then you try to allocate the array on the stack. The stack is normally in the low megabyte range (as in one to four). You try to allocate *over* four megabytes, which will not work.

The easy way to solve this is to allocate it dynamically off the heap:

```
char* buffer = new char[size + 1];

// Do operations on `buffer`

delete[] buffer;
```

Comment: There is a compiler config for stack and heap sizes if its msvc.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Yes, but it sets the stack for the *whole* process, and increasing this just because of one single function may be wasteful.

Comment: Or just a `vector`, which has the definite advantage of being exception-safe.

Comment: but but even it don't work in the range of  400000 . it should do that because 1 mega byte is 1 048 576 bytes
any idea why it do so ?? and i couldn't understand  how you are trying to allocate the array on the stack ?? how i am doing is shown in my code. i couldn't understand how you are asking to do ?? please explain it ??

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT 4348928 bytes is 4.1 MB, and you also need space for all other variables, arguments and of course the *previous* functions (and their variables) in the call chain. Not to mention that the compiler (and maybe the hardware) also puts data on the stack.

Comment: 1 more question Joachim. what if i don't delete the dynamically declared  buffer ?? it still works fine

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT If you continue the program afterwards, then you have a memory leak.

Comment: +1, @JoachimPileborg, I was looking for a long time for explanation of  why stack size limited. So, thank you. Can you give some pointers of where I can get more information about this?

Comment: @ i am doing delete[] buffer; just after the use of buffer is over. it dont't give any error and there is no problem at all but i don't know why it give  buffer = 0x0000000005890070 <Bad Ptr> , CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated on debugging..Any Idea ??

Comment: Pointers is for more `C` users. It is better to avoid them if possible. Better use containers.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to you because static data are stored in stack and its size is a few MB. If you allocate memory dynamically your data goes into heap and it is much bigger.

In your case I would use containers. Probably `vector`.

```
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
```

Containers are safer then pointers and much safer then dynamically allocations because containers auto delete stuff if you don't use it anymore. Also you can always safely increase size of container just pushing another value.

If you need to pass it to function you can pass reference (it is probably the best option), however you can pass pointer to first element by doing this: `&buffer[0]` **(this works only with `vector`)**.

What is more you can iterate through all containers by getting pointer to data.

```
for (std::vector::iterator it = buffer.begin(); it != buffer.end(); ++it)
{/*some stuff*/}
```

Iterations looks the same with any type of container.

What is more, you allocate 4348928 chars, it is about 4MB. But if you need to allocate lets say 300MB allocation with `new` usually fails (the same with `vector`). For such a big allocations you should use `std::deque`.

Answer (score -1):

Use Pointer as the local function memory is allocated from stack and it will not be able to get that much fetch.